# Spline gradient not displaying

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart where by there can be a number of splines laid over the top. When introducing a gradient fill the columns display correctly, but the splines are blank.

[image: Column Chart - Highcharts]

Do i need to set a property? as they display normally with a non gradient fill.

Comment: Please replicate your chart as live example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mhoward90/mk8Nx/

Comment: The spline doesn't display on the chart in chrome, but does on IE8. until you export.. then it's blank again

Comment: Indeed it looks like possibly bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3266)